# How can I change the background colour with each route page using react (without bootstrap)?

Tags: reactjs, routes, react-router, background-color

I am trying to change the background colour for my route pages but I am having some difficulty. If I use regular css it will only change the background color of the div as opposed to the entire page? My goal is to get the team pages to reflect their team colors.

Here is my [gitHub](https://github.com/amberleighpurnis/tcsl-website), thanks in advance for your help.

A

Answer (score 0):

You first need to store the color for teams at some place. I think MenuItem.js will be the right place for this.

MenuItems.js (Changed path values to render Team Component)

```
export const MenuItems = [
  {
    title: "Baby Zepps",
    path: "/teams/baby-zepps",
    cName: "dropdown-link",
    color: "green",
  },
  {
    title: "Bad Dog",
    path: "/teams/bad-dog",
    cName: "dropdown-link",
    color: "blue",
  },
];
```

Now Somehow while selecting the team from the dropdown you need to pass down the resp. team color to the component being rendered on team click.
As these elements in team dropdowns are **Link** components, we can set **state** in these Link components which will help us pass data to resp. component being rendered on this Link click.

In Dropdown.js,

```
<Link
  className={item.cName}
  to={{
     pathname: item.path,
     state: {
       color: item.color,
     },
  }}
  onClick={() => setClick(false)}
>
```

So, this state value being set in **Link** component. can be accessed in **Teams** component using

> props.location.state.color

So, in Teams Component:

```
export default function Teams(props) {
  return (
    <div style={{backgroundColor: props.location.state.color}}>
      <h1>Hello from Teams</h1>
    </div>
  );
}
```

So, this is how Component in browser looks like:

[image]

[image]